# Buscar un string en un array en PHP llamando a una API

Tags: php, array, api, arraylist, webapi

quiero buscar una cadena dentro de un array que me regresa una API

este es lo que me regresa la API

```
[
{
    "id": "5a162db4-4443-4ee8-828a-372562230bf9",
    "supplyItemNumber": "PDH2OS001",
    "type": "Machine",
    "category": "Coolants & Lubricants",
    "priority": "Alto",
    "group": "Lubricants",
    "description": "",
    "customerUnitPrice": 0.00,
    "inventoryUnit": "Litre",
    "briefDescription": "",
    "accountId": null,
    "manufacturerCode": null,
    "supplierId": null,
    "manufacturerItemNumber": "",
    "manufacturerItemRevision": "",
    "manufacturerText": "",
    "createdDate": "2018-12-11T22:57:58Z",
    "createdById": "6e6a5c41-f62c-460b-96f4-fcab58381bbe",
    "modifiedDate": "2019-03-06T15:46:56Z",
    "modifiedById": "6e6a5c41-f62c-460b-96f4-fcab58381bbe",
    "taxCodeNumber": null,
    "maxQuantity": 0.00,
    "minQuantity": 0.00
},
{
    "id": "96d85b76-5231-4ce4-95fc-7fa9c915caab",
    "supplyItemNumber": "PDH2OS002",
    "type": "Machine",
    "category": "Coolants & Lubricants",
    "priority": "Alto",
    "group": "Lubricants",
    "description": "",
    "customerUnitPrice": 0.00,
    "inventoryUnit": "Litre",
    "briefDescription": "",
    "accountId": null,
    "manufacturerCode": null,
    "supplierId": null,
    "manufacturerItemNumber": "",
    "manufacturerItemRevision": "",
    "manufacturerText": "",
    "createdDate": "2018-12-11T22:57:58Z",
    "createdById": "6e6a5c41-f62c-460b-96f4-fcab58381bbe",
    "modifiedDate": "2019-03-06T15:46:45Z",
    "modifiedById": "6e6a5c41-f62c-460b-96f4-fcab58381bbe",
    "taxCodeNumber": null,
    "maxQuantity": 0.00,
    "minQuantity": 0.00
```

}
]

y este es mi codigo con el que lo busco

```html
var_export ($response);
$indice = array_search($direccion,$response,false);
echo "El número 5 está en el indice: " . $indice;
```

pero me regresa el siguiente error

Warning: array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in

Answer (score 0):

el error te aparece porque el API te devuelve el array como json es decir va a estar en tu variable $response como un string, entonces el error dice que requiere un array pero le estas pasando un String, lo puedes pasar a array de la siguiente forma:

```
$response = json_decode($response);
```